# LWJGL - Picking Help (Surface of plane isn't a consistent value)

Tags: java, lwjgl

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siLjUjoYJgw&feature=youtu.be

The video explains it all. I've rounded the X and Z axis so you can see the Y axis value better, but it happens with X and Z as well.

Problem: The value should stay at a solid "1", but it fluctuates.

```
public Vector3D pickBlock() {
    glPushMatrix();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, -1);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);

        IntBuffer viewport = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16);
        FloatBuffer modelview = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        FloatBuffer projection = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        FloatBuffer winZ = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(1);
        float winX, winY;
        FloatBuffer position = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3);
        glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
        glGetFloat(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
        glGetInteger(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
        winX = (float)Display.getWidth() / 2;
        winY = (float)viewport.get(3) - (float)Display.getHeight() / 2;
        glReadPixels(Display.getWidth() / 2, (int)winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, winZ);
        gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ.get(), modelview, projection, viewport, position);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glPopMatrix();
    return new Vector3D(position.get(0), position.get(1), position.get(2));
}
```

This is where I render the world:

```
 glPushMatrix();
        for(int x = (int) (player.x - RENDER_DISTANCE ); x < (int) (player.x + RENDER_DISTANCE); x++) {
            for(int z = (int) (player.z - RENDER_DISTANCE); z < (int) (player.z + RENDER_DISTANCE); z++) {
                if(player.cam.frustum.pointInFrustum(-x * 2, player.y + 1.2f, -z * 2)) {
                    drawTile((x * 2), 1, (z * 2));
                }
            }
        }   
        Vector3D selLookPos = pickBlock();
    glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Don't use [deprecate OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL)...

Comment: How would I go about doing this for Java OpenGL 3.0? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Similar, but you should follow some tutorials because you need to write your own shader program and manage the matrices in your own. One thing that you don't want is to instantiate a new buffer every `pickBlock()`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've figured out rendering with VBOs now. All I need to figure out is how to do the picking.

Comment: As you did, with `glReadPixels`, bind fbo, set `readBuffer` and read the pixel/s you want

Comment: Will `readBuffer` return a XYZ coordinate? If not, is there an easy way to get the XYZ?